# Найти минимальное и максимальное из чётных положительных чисел

Tags: python

Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Во всех тестах ОК, кроме одного.
Ошибка во время выполнения программы.

Задача с информатикса:

> Найти минимальное и максимальное из чётных положительных чисел, записанных в файле `input.txt`. Количество чисел неизвестно. Если в файле нет чётных положительных чисел, нужно вывести число 0. Результат записать в файл `output.txt`
>
> Входные данные.
>   Целые числа записаны в файле `input.txt` в столбик, по одному в строке. Ввод заканчивается тогда, когда заканчиваются данные в файле.
>
> Выходные данные.
>   Программа должна вывести в файл `output.txt` минимальное и максимальное из чётных положительных чисел, разделив их пробелом. Если в файле нет чётных положительных чисел, нужно вывести число 0.
>
> Примеры
>
> входные данные
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> -5
> -8
> ```
>
> выходные данные
>
> ```
> 2 4
> ```

Много различных вариаций решения придумал, но кину это:

**Решение:**

```
f=open('input.txt')
g=open('output.txt','w')
s=[int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
s=[i for i in s if (i>0 and i %2 == 0)]
if s != []:
    print(str(min(s))+' '+str(max(s)), file = g)
else:
    print('0', file = g)
f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: Ошибка? Какая??

Comment: Возможно, файл ОЧЕНЬ большой и просто не влезает в оперативку. Можно попытаться попробовать читать не весь файл сразу, а по одному числу за раз

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ Спасибо))) Ты был прав, как я сразу не понял. До этого решал и все время перебирал по отдельности, потом понял, что можно взять целиком. И забыл про перебор строк по отдельности) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    myList = [int(item) for sublist in [line.split() for line in f] for item in sublist if int(item) > 0]
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as g:
        print("{} {}".format(min(myList), max(myList)) if len(myList)==4 else "0", file = g)
```

Comment: Благодаря вам исправил код, но ошибка не пропала.

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо огромное уже решили))) Ваш код помог мне укоротить свой ^^

Comment: Осталось в stdlib python добавить функцию getOnlyPositivesAndReturnMinMaxFromThem(list) и решение задачи свести только к гугингу :)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что я взял весь текст сразу, а он слишком длинный. Необходимо перебирать каждую строку отдельно!